# Magento grid disable sorting and filtering

Tags: sorting, magento, filter, grid

How to disable sorting and filtering  on a column in Magento grid

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The easiest way is to do it in _prepareColumns() method.

```
  $this->addColumn('item', array(
      'header'    => Mage::helper('module')->__('Object'),
      'index'     => 'item',
      'filter'    => false,
      'sortable'  => false
  ));
```

Comment: Thanks Alexei, One more thing could you tell me is it 
'filter'  => false or 'filter  => 'false' 
 'filter'  => false leads to 404 page not found

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Filter shouldn't lead to 404 error. When exactly do you get error?

Comment: how to to it on ui_component?

Answer (score 7):

For Disable filter for all columns in custom grid, you can use the following methods.

Set the following methods `$this->setFilterVisibility(false);` in your custom Grid.php(Block) file .

```
 public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();            
        $this->setFilterVisibility(false);
    }
```